# Session logout after visiting extern site

Tags: php, session, paypal, payment, logout

I have a login/register script (php) and users are logged in.
But when they visit an extern site (such like paypal to make a donation for the site) after they come back to my site, they are logged out.
This is a problem, because i cannot complete the payment transaction automatically, because the user is logged out.

I work with:

$Account->logged

Can anyone help? Or does someone have a suggestion why this is happening?

Greetings and much thanks!

Comment: `session` life time is ????

Comment: The problem is: Some people are not logged out after returning, some people are. (Within same time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call site like this address:
`www.site.com`
And `paypal` back link like this:
`http://www.site.com` Or `site.com` 
Session reset. Because your link changed.
So..Redirecting non-www to www with `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You are right! But how to fix this: Some people use with www. and some without. 

I am logged out indeed when i visit same page with www. when i logged in without.

Comment: Redirect all link to `www.site.com` and change `paypal` back link to `www.site.com`

Comment: But what if some people using: http://example.com  to get to the website, and some people: www.example.com  to get to the website?

Comment: Use `.htaccess` file to redirect link like `site.com` to `www.site.com`.See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the session timeout on your sessions is extremely short, or maybe your login system is automatically logging people out when the browser is redirected to a different domain or something like that..??  Should be able to disable something like that pretty easily.

That's the first thing I'd do, though, is check to see if/when the sessions are dying or being cleared.

Comment: The problem is: Some people are not logged out after returning, some people are. (Within same time)

Comment: Ok, well again, you need to try and reproduce that, and follow the sessions.  If they're logged out the session is dying on them one way or another, so there has to be something that's triggering that.